# Issue with fgtecsv and invalid filehandle

Tags: php

The following code echos "Null" but how is this possible?
The `fopen` returns not false (i.e. a valid file handler) but the `fgetcsv` returns NULL which means invalid file handler given. I don't understand this.

```
if ($fh = fopen("2014_01.csv", 'r') !== FALSE) {
    if ($test = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';') == NULL)
        echo "Null";
    fclose($fh);
} else
    echo "fh error";
```

Comment: try to put this $test = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';') before the if, maybe it works but not on the if syntax

Comment: Because of the incorrect order of evaluation (see my answer below), `$fh` gets the value `TRUE` which is not a valid handle. PHP is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). The comparison (`==`) has higher precedence than the assignment (`=`), that's why it evaluates like this:

```
if ($fh = (fopen() !== FALSE)) {
    if ($test = (fgetcsv() == NULL))
```

And this is not what you want. Put parenthesis around the assignments:

```
if (($fh = fopen("2014_01.csv", 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    if (($test = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';')) == NULL)
```